# Checking if software is installed in SSH session

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I am trying to check whether a certain package is installed on remote machine in bash script.

If I execute the following statement on the machine itself the result is 1 (installed) in file check.txt, which is correct:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed" > /home/someuser/check.txt
```

However, if I execute the same command in SSH session, the result is always 0.

Can somebody explain why and how to correct this?

Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash
ADDRESS=SOMEUSER@$SOMESERVER

function run {
    ssh $ADDRESS /bin/bash $@
}

run << SSHCONNECTION

dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed" > /home/someuser/check.txt

SSHCONNECTION
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your script: either `run << \SSHCONNECTION`
or `dpkg-query -W -f='\${Status}' nano`. 
Currently, your local shell is trying to expand `${Status}`
(yes, even though it’s in single quotes) because it’s in a here document. 
(And it’s presumably expanding to a null string.)

The first part is fairly well documented. 
The POSIX [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) specification,
Section [2.7.4 Here-Document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04) says:

> The format is … `[n]<<word` …
>         ︙
>   If any part of *`word`* is quoted…
>   the here-document lines shall not be expanded.
>         ︙
>   If no part of *`word`* is quoted,
>   all lines of the here-document shall be expanded …

[bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) says essentially the same thing.

The second part is not so clearly documented. 
The above sentence from the POSIX specification continues:

> If no part of *`word`* is quoted,
>   all lines of the here-document shall be expanded
>   for parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. 
>   In this case, the <backslash> in the input behaves
>   as the <backslash> inside double-quotes (see [Double-Quotes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03)).

That section also says,

> The here-document shall be treated as a single word
>   that begins after the next <newline>
>   and continues until there is a line
>   containing only the delimiter and a <newline>, …

By contrast, Section [2.3 Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) says:

> When an **io_here** token (i.e., a `<<` or `<<-`)
>   has been recognized by the grammar (see [Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10)),
>   one or more of the subsequent lines
>   immediately following the next NEWLINE token
>   form the body of one or more here-documents
>   and shall be parsed according to the rules of [Here-Document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04).
>
> When it is not processing an **io_here**,
>   the shell shall break its input into tokens
>   by applying the first applicable rule below …

and then lists ten rules, including

> 4. If the current character is <backslash>,
>      single-quote, or double-quote and it is not quoted,
>      it shall affect quoting for subsequent characters
>      up to the end of the quoted text.

So I guess we need to read between the lines to see that
text in here-documents is treated
almost as if it is already in double quotes,
and it is processed ***only*** for
parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion
(and limited backslash processing),
***and not*** for quote removal.

---

Also, you should always quote your shell variable references
(e.g., `"$ADDRESS"` and `"$@"`) unless you have a good reason not to,
and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Comment: I'm quite new to Bash and really appreciate your detailed explanation. Thank you.